# make a textview width proportional to imageview above

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

my layout is very simple. i use a vertical relative layout which contains an imageview on top of 2 textviews (heading and text). In portrait it looks fine. However in landscape it happens, that the imageview will not fill out the whole width of the screen but the text below still does. that doesnt look good. is there a simply way i can make the text width as wide as the imageview above, so all views will have the same right boarder on any screen size?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/picture" />

<TextView
    style="@style/DescriptionTitle"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/heading"   />

<TextView
    style="@style/DescriptionText"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"   />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView1"` to your TextView. You may need to use `android:layout_width="0dp"`; also on the same TextView.

Comment: wow that does actually do the job. thanks so much. but i dont get it, could you explain the "logic" behind it?

Comment: `layout_alignLeft` anchors this view's left edge to the left egde of the specified anchor view, and `layout_alignRight` anchors this view's right edge to the right edge of the specified anchor view.

Answer (score 0):

insted of using 
 `android:src="@drawable/picture"` 

   use
 `android:background="@drawable/picture"` hope it will work for you